# Android Wear 2.0.4 fails to find class "com.google.android.aidl.BaseStub"

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

My Wear project (WatchFace) fails to run using Android Wear 2.0.4 where it builds and runs successfully with Android Wear 2.0.3.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/aidl/BaseStub;
                                                 at com.debiana.getoffmylawn.LawnWatchService.onCreateEngine(LawnWatchService.java:69)
                                                 at com.debiana.getoffmylawn.LawnWatchService.onCreateEngine(LawnWatchService.java:52)
                                                 at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1163)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
```

The dependencies in my app build.gradle is simply:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'
}
```

And all that has changed there is 2.0.3 has become 2.0.4

Comment: I can confirm that. Possibly a bug?

Comment: Indeed, 2.0.4 is causing crashes for all Android Wear devices I have here. I suggest downgrading to 2.0.3 for the time being.